# Creating a Symbolic Link in Java - Access denied

Tags: java, symlink, access-denied

I am having a problem creating symbolic links in Java. Basically when I run the program I get Access Denied in the error log. I have searched on here and on google and all I seem to be able to find is answers involving packaging the code into an exe with launch4j or something similar and including a manifest that grants administrator privileges?

I am fairly new to Java so I might just be misunderstanding the ways you can deal with security, but it seems strange that with all of the functionality of Java, there would be no way to even prompt a user to ask if they wished to grant administrator privileges without having to export it?

I realise I may just be getting completely confused here, as like I say, I am pretty new to Java, and I would be happy to do some more reading if there is an article or whatever that I have been unable to find!

Thanks in advance, I have found this site incredibly helpful so far.

This is the line of code I am using:

```
Files.createSymbolicLink(externalLocation.toPath(), originalLocation.toPath());
```

where `externalLocation` and `originalLocation` are File objects that include correct file paths.

Comment: Nobody says that this lowlevel method is called by Desktop applications only. So expecting a dialog for privilege elevation to popup automatically in this method is a bit odd. You won’t find any programming language offering such feature. You have to program it by yourself— and it’s not an easy task even with the native Windows API.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear there, I was asking how you would program it to ask.

Comment: Actually, you have probably pointed me in the right direction there, maybe that is my real question and I have been searching for the wrong thing.